# Scrapy: Extracting data from source and its links

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Edited question to link to original:

[Scrapy getting data from links within table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257870/scrapy-getting-data-from-links-within-table)

From the link https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/trottiewillielast.html

I am trying to get info from the main table as well as the data within the other 2 links within the table. I managed to pull from one, but question is going to the other link and appending the data in one line.

```
from urlparse import urljoin

import scrapy

from texasdeath.items import DeathItem

class DeathItem(Item):
    firstName = Field()
    lastName = Field()
    Age = Field()
    Date = Field()
    Race = Field()
    County = Field()
    Message = Field()
    Passage = Field()

class DeathSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "death"
    allowed_domains = ["tdcj.state.tx.us"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//table/tbody/tr')
        for site in sites:
            item = DeathItem()

            item['firstName'] = site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            item['lastName'] = site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['Age'] = site.xpath('td[7]/text()').extract()
            item['Date'] = site.xpath('td[8]/text()').extract()
            item['Race'] = site.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
            item['County'] = site.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()

            url = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[3]/a/@href").extract_first())
            url2 = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[2]/a/@href").extract_first())
            if url.endswith("html"):
                request = scrapy.Request(url, meta={"item": item,"url2" : url2}, callback=self.parse_details)
                yield request
            else:
                yield item
def parse_details(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]
    url2 = response.meta["url2"]
    item['Message'] = response.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Last Statement')]/following-sibling::p/text()").extract()
    request = scrapy.Request(url2, meta={"item": item}, callback=self.parse_details2)
    return request

def parse_details2(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]
    item['Passage'] = response.xpath("//p/text()").extract_first()
    return item
```

I understand how we pass arguments to a request and meta. But still unclear of the flow, at this point I am unsure whether this is possible or not. I have viewed several examples including the ones below:

[using scrapy extracting data inside links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094057/using-scrapy-extracting-data-inside-links)

[How can i use multiple requests and pass items in between them in scrapy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910357/how-can-i-use-multiple-requests-and-pass-items-in-between-them-in-scrapy-python/25571270#25571270)

Technically the data will reflect the main table just with both links containing data from within its link.

Appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in this case is in this piece of code

```
if url.endswith("html"):
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={"item": item}, callback=self.parse_details)
    else:
        yield item

if url2.endswith("html"):
        yield scrapy.Request(url2, meta={"item": item}, callback=self.parse_details2)
    else:
        yield item
```

By requesting a link you are creating a new "thread" that will take its own course of life so, the function parse_details wont be able to see what is being done in parse_details2, the way I would do it is call one within each other this way

```
url = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[2]/a/@href").extract_first())

url2 = urljoin(response.url, site.xpath("td[3]/a/@href").extract_first()

if url.endswith("html"):
    request=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_details)
    request.meta['item']=item
    request.meta['url2']=url2
    yield request
elif url2.endswith("html"):
    request=scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_details2)
    request.meta['item']=item
    yield request

else:
    yield item


def parse_details(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]
    url2 = response.meta["url2"]
    item['About Me'] = response.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'About Me')]/following-sibling::p/text()").extract()
    if url2:
        request=scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_details2)
        request.meta['item']=item
        yield request
    else:
        yield item
```

This code hasn't been tested thoroughly so comment as you test

Comment: Getting some sort of error with `url2 = response.meta("url2") TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`.  Might be how we are passing the response.meta.

Comment: Should be because how we are accessing the dict.

Comment: Updated my code and linked to my original question.